# How to extract and modify userData from node in Swift?

Tags: swift, user-data

I have added my own userData to a set of nodes and am able to retrieve this information, but don't know how to extract it in a way that I can use it. From this line of code

```
println(node.userData!)
```

I get the output in the following form in the output console

> {
>   10 = 0;
>   }

The first number represents an integer index value and the second a boolean. The index values are different for each node while the boolean is set to false for all of them. I need to change the boolean to true in every instance, and I need to extract the index value to use in further conditional statements, such as

```
 if indexValue = 1 {
some code here
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `index` and `boolean` values separately, it's better to store them as two key value pairs.

```
node.userData = ["index": 10, "boolean" : false ]
```

You can extract the index with the following code.

```
if let index = node.userData?.valueForKey("index") as? Int {
    println(index)
}
```

To modify the values you can do,

```
node.userData?.setValue(true, forKey: "boolean")
node.userData?.setValue(11, forKey: "index")
```

Comment: you are a lifesaver! :D Thanks so much, I now understand MUCH better as to how to use this type of syntax!